# Specific log4net-logfile for PayPal

Tags: c#, paypal, log4net, log4net-configuration

Is it possible to specify the logfile in the App.config?

I found these parameters in .NET: 
https://github.com/paypal/sdk-core-dotnet/wiki/SDK-Configuration-Parameters

In PHP it seems to be possible (Logging):
https://github.com/paypal/sdk-core-php/wiki/Configuring-the-SDK

Now, the informations will be saved in the first of many stated logfiles.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Yes, it is possible to specify the logfile in your config.  The [PayPal .NET SDK wiki](https://github.com/paypal/PayPal-NET-SDK/wiki/Configuration#log4net-config-settings-optional) shows what information you need to add to your config file:

```xml
<configuration>
  <configSections>
    <section name="log4net" type="log4net.Config.Log4NetConfigurationSectionHandler, log4net"/>
  </configSections>

  <!-- log4net settings -->
  <log4net>
    <appender name="FileAppender" type="log4net.Appender.FileAppender">
      <file value="my_app.log"/>
      <appendToFile value="true"/>
      <layout type="log4net.Layout.PatternLayout">
        <conversionPattern value="%date [%thread] %-5level %logger [%property{NDC}] %message%newline"/>
      </layout>
    </appender>
    <root>
      <level value="DEBUG"/>
      <appender-ref ref="FileAppender"/>
    </root>
  </log4net>

  <!-- 
  App-specific settings. Here we specify which PayPal logging classes are enabled.
    PayPal.Log.Log4netLogger: Provides base log4net logging functionality
    PayPal.Log.DiagnosticsLogger: Provides more thorough logging of system diagnostic information and tracing code execution
  -->
  <appSettings>
    <!-- Diagnostics logging is only available in a Full Trust environment. -->
    <!-- <add key="PayPalLogger" value="PayPal.Log.DiagnosticsLogger, PayPal.Log.Log4netLogger"/> -->
    <add key="PayPalLogger" value="PayPal.Log.Log4netLogger"/>
  </appSettings>
</configuration>
```

Replace `my_app.log` with your own logfile name.

Comment: In my App.config file, there already exist properties for another logs. I want to distinguish between PayPal actions and actions from other features of my program.

So, I have to configure the PayPal-API with the name of the specific logfile.

Comment: Or is it possible to turn off logging?

Comment: The PayPal log entries will include the full, namespaced class name.  If you want to change it to have some other text or formatting, just change the `<conversionPattern>` element's `value` attribute in the above XML.  To turn SDK logging off completely, just leave this information out of your config.

Comment: Thanks! I created a new Logfile which has no parameters in the value field. Now, no logs will be stored.